# PHP Curl giving Bad Request - Invalid Header

Tags: php, xml, curl

1. When i am trying to hit the curl with xml headers as well as post fields. I am getting error as bad request. I don't know what's going wrong, can any one help with this?
2. Mobile field data passed in header is triple des converted

---

```
$url="www.test.com/api";
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a><b>hai</b></a>';

$xml_header = trim('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mobile>4xKReHFU60Ova0aqHxZldg==</mobile>
')  ;

$headers = array(
"Content-type: text/xml",
"Content-length: " .strlen($xml_header),
"Connection: close",
);
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
//return the transfer as a string 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("xml"=>$xml));
// Check if any error occurred
if(!curl_errno($ch))
{
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

echo "<pre>";var_dump($info);
echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
//echo 'Took ' . $info['total_time'] . ' seconds to send a request to ' . $info['url'];
}                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);exit;
```

Comment: have you tried `application/xml` instead?

Comment: You set content length to the length of one string, but don't use it anywhere as far as I can see. Then set content type to text/XML, but are sending something that is not valid XML and length is not what you say it is.

Comment: tried application/xml no change

Comment: Your $xml contains header, and you pass it again at $xml_header to $headers array. It seems it's duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

***Bad Request*** is normally send from the server you interact with to tell you that there was a *serious* problem with the request, most often a *malformed* HTTP request up to that point that the remote server does not know at all what to do with it.

That is to say: You hit the jackpot of breaking it.

Remove bit after bit from your request until you get a more specific error message that can guide you more precisely when adding things again to not run into the same error again.

This is only general advice. The problem I could spot more concretely has been asked and answered already and I therefore closed it against a duplicate that should remind you, that having curl dealing with the content-length is most often easier as when you try to deal yourself with it (no pun intended).